# Symmetry of spherical ice crystals

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry, crystals, ice

Page no. 291 of *Hidden Unity in Nature's Laws* by John C. Taylor says the following - 
"*Take a spherical water drop.
No special direction is picked out by such a drop. If we rotate it
nothing has changed. A spherical ice crystal (assuming it to be a perfect crystal) does define special directions, by the way the molecules
are lined up in regular arrays. If we rotate it, it does in general
change, because the array is rotated*". 
**Problem** - I can't see how a *spherical ice crystal defines special directions* - it seems to me to be like any other (**rotational**) symmetry-preserving spherical shape. Any explanation/resources would be welcome.

Comment: All crystals have directionality to them, and regular ice as a hexagonal close packed crystal is no exception.

Comment: @JonCuster The rotational invariance is evident when we are able to see [the hexagonal shape of the crystal at the molecular level](https://crystalsymmetry.files.wordpress.com/2018/04/ice_ih_molecular_arrangement.png). I imagine a ["spherical ice crystal"](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQPGdMIjcpHNdu4SmCGVAIujGn4xIOvnBpSrA&usqp=CAU) as a transparent glass marble which clearly has rotational symmetry. If we are looking at the molecular level, then it's a hexagon and not a "spherical" crystal - how can we call a hexagon a sphere? Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Any shape will have some atomic irregularity on the surface, but a single crystal ball of ice can be pretty close to spherical (ignoring surface rearrangements). But, with an x-ray diffractometer one can clearly see what the orientation of the crystal is.